# VS Express 2013 C++ with MySQL Connector stmt->executeQuery() error

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, mysql-connector

So I finally got VS 2013  C++ to connect with mySQL using the Connector C and C++ and I know this because I am able to add a table into my DB using the stmt->execute() function.

Now, I am trying to get the rows using the ResultSet to retrieve from function executeQuery, but this error shows up:
[image]
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "mysql_driver.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

#define dbHOST "tcp://127.0.0.1:3306"
#define dbUSER "root"
#define dbPASS "root"
#define dbDB   "db_test"

using namespace std;
using namespace sql;

int main()
{
    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *res;

    driver = sql::mysql::get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect(dbHOST, dbUSER, dbPASS);

    stmt = con->createStatement();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM test";
    res = stmt->executeQuery(query.c_str());

    while (res->next()) {
        cout << "id = " << res->getInt(1); 
        cout << ", label = '" << res->getString("label") << "'" << endl;
    }

    delete res;
    delete stmt;
    delete con;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Under the output pane, it shows this as well:

```
First-chance exception at 0x77661D4D in MySQLConnect.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: sql::SQLException at memory location 0x0088FB5C.

Unhandled exception at 0x77661D4D in MySQLConnect.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: sql::SQLException at memory location 0x0088FB5C.
```

Under the call stack after I hit F5 and it breaks, it shows this:

> MySQLConnect.exe!main() Line 35 C++

Line 35 is the line with **res = stmt->executeQuery(query.c_str());**

Let me know if you need more information on my code / settings.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly me, I found out what is the problem.
I have to add in a line:

```
stmt->execute("USE " dbDB);
```

before I can do any further query for that database. The snippet is now like this:

```
stmt = con->createStatement(); 
stmt->execute("USE " dbDB);              // <-- This line, change dbDB to your own
string query = "SELECT * FROM test";     // <- before all of these below
res = stmt->executeQuery(query.c_str());
```

I hope this helps!